# How can I determine in TS if an element has overflown | Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UImd.png)

Here the text "Pulmonary" gets overflown due to less space, What I want is if "Pulmonary" doesnt have space it should not be rendered instead other options ( selected ) should be rendered if it have enough space.

I have tried searching for many solutions, What I have come across is that if a "text" gets overflown its offset width will be greater than scroll width, so I have written a pipe so that overflown text wont be rendered.

I'm getting the offsetwidth and scrollwidth same.

Any other solutions?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is the [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#browser_compatibility)

Comment: But wouldn't you rather use `white-space: normal` or `text-overflow: ellipsis`?

Comment: @Pieterjan we  are trying to represent text in full form, we dont need ellipses